# C# Рефлексия, Сборки, Объект с конкретным интерфейсом

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Пишу mini-framework для упрощённого создания приложений, поддерживающих концепцию Plug-in. Есть интерфейс `IExtension` , через который идёт всё взаимодействие, и есть папка в проекте в которую закидываются откомпилированные `.dll` решения с кодом, и классом, реализующим данный интерфейс. Вопрос звучит так, как из длл-ки вытащить только тот объект, который реализует нужный мне интерфейс?

У меня был вариант перебрать в сборке все классы, пока не найдётся нужный, но это стукнет по производительности будь здоров.

Пока писал всё это, пришла ещё идея помечать нужный класс кастомным атрибутом ExtensionAttribute. Звучит как вариант, но мне бы не хотелось нагромождать код лишним синтаксисом.

И так вопрос: как мне вытянуть `SomeClass : IExtension`, из .dll, без большого удара по производительности, и по возможности, без атрибутов?

Comment: `но это стукнет по производительности будь здоров` мне кажется, что не должно особо стукнуть. Попробуйте провести эксперимент.

Comment: никак, если ты не знаешь конкретные классы, тебе придется бежать по всем и проверять - имплементирует класс интерфейс или нет

Comment: В книге Рихтера CLR via C# описан способ создания плагинов именно с помощью интерфейса, как у вас. Вот [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/449a6e3f-74ac-4239-adde-a41d2ef63365/10571086107910761072108510801077?forum=fordesktopru) он же описан. / Можно взять фреймворк [MEF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/), который предназначен для создания расширяемых приложений. В нём как раз используются атрибуты.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, как раз занят чтением этой, мозговыносящей(в хорошем плане) книги, пока ещё не добрался до этого момента, Спасибо за инфу

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov тем не менее, MEF скорее всего просто элегантно скрывает рефлексию.

Comment: @iluxa1810 - да, конечно, там под капотом рефлексия. Он перебирает объекты в сборке и ищет те, у которых нужные атрибуты.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov , задача состоит именно в написании своего(изначально курсовой проект, но теперь планирую как основную деятельность, т.к в гитхабе шаром покати, а тут идея интересная), хотя, я с удовольствие подчерпну вдохновение из этого фрейма, спасибо!

Comment: @tym32167, я придумал, как чучуть уменьшить выборку классов, и перебираю только коллекцию Assemby.ExportedTypes, где находятся только классы с модификатором public

Comment: Если вас сильно парит производительность, то можно после скана сохранить куда то информацию о хеше/версии/ключе сборки и найденных типах, чтобы не парсить одну и ту же сборку дважды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

И так. Исходя из полученных комментариев. У меня как было два варианта, так и осталось. Я посидел и подумал, что интерфейсы это круто, и оставил IExtension. Но! Атрибуты тоже выглядят вкусно(можно будет в резюме указать, "Знаю Рефлексию" :D) и вот к какой реализации я пришёл.
Интерфейс:

```
    public interface IExtension
{

    string Name { get; }
    string CreatorName { get; }
    string Version { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Используется для инициализации нужных компонентов 
    /// </summary>
    void Init();

    /// <summary>
    /// Старт приложения
    /// object - объект приложения
    /// </summary>
    object Start();

}
```

Затем, я создал базовый класс на основе интерфейса  с реализацией обязательного функционала

```
[IAExtension]
public abstract class Extension : IExtension
{
    private bool isShow = true;

    public string Name { get; set; } = "UnSet";
    public string CreatorName { get; set; } = "UnSet";
    public string Version { get; set; } = "1.0.0";

    public Visibility Show
    {
        get => (isShow) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        set => isShow = (value == Visibility.Visible);
    }


    protected List<string> FriendlyExtensions { get; } = new List<string>();

    protected ExConnection Connection { get; set; }

    public abstract void Init();
    /// <summary>
    /// outParam - using for fill extraData
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="outParam"></param>
    public abstract object Start();

    public bool Friendly(string name)
    {
        foreach (var friendlyExt in FriendlyExtensions)
            if (friendlyExt == name)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

Если присмотреться, то вы обнаружите в объявлении типа Атрибут `[IAExtension]`, это кастомный атрибут без реализации, служит он как раз для того, чтобы при подгрузке объектов из .dll определить, является ли подгружаемый класс - расширением. (Правда в таком случае наличие IExtension является фиктивным, но я его оставил, на всякий случай)

И на всякий, скину код загрузки, вдруг понадобится кому

Reflector - основной класс для Отражения

```
  public class Reflector
{
    //fileName - полный путь до .dll
    //Создаёт сборку на основе .dll файла
    public Assembly GetAssemblyFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName.EndsWith(".dll"))
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
        else throw new ArgumentException($"{fileName} не  является .dll файлом");
    }

    //Подгружает(+ сразу создаёт Extension из скомпилированной сборки)
    public Extension GetExtensionFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
    {
        var type = typeof(IAExtensionAttribute);
        foreach (var obj in assembly.ExportedTypes)
            if (obj.GetCustomAttribute(type) != null)
                return assembly.CreateInstance(obj.FullName) as Extension;

        return null;
    }
}
```

Метод, который пользуется всем этим ужасом, и возвращает список добавленных в приложение расширений

```
    private List<Extension> LoadExtensions()
    {
        var reflector = new Reflector();
        var extsPath = Directory.GetFiles(loadPath).Where(file => file.EndsWith(".dll")).ToArray();
        if (extsPath.Length > 0)
        {
            var resoultList = new List<Extension>();
            foreach (var ext in extsPath)
            {
                var compiltedAssembly = reflector.GetAssemblyFromFile(ext);
                resoultList.Add(reflector.GetExtensionFromAssembly(compiltedAssembly));
            }
            return resoultList;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `return assembly.CreateInstance(obj.FullName) as Extension;` сначала проверье, что тип у вас вообще наследует/реализует `Extension`, а потом уже создавайте экзеипляр. Ну и вы его в том же домене создаете? А как же безопасность?

Comment: @tym32167, по поводу безопасности, я только начал изучать рефлексию, сборки и устройство CLR. Я задумывался по поводу этого, пока рано, но я учту, спасибо. По поводу проверки на наследование, я пока что сам с собой условился, что все все расширения точно наследуют Extension

Comment: рано -я имел ввиду что я ещё пока не знаю достаточно, для обеспечения такого функционала, а не то, что мне лень :D

Comment: ну и я бы создавал каким то контейнером а не просто CreateInstance, на случай, например, если расширениб понадобится какой то из ваших основных классов.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что особого удара по производительности быть не должно, если вы будете работать с объектом через интерфейс, что позволит исключить многие проблемы. Например, упаковку/распаковку. По идее, вам рефлексия только нужна при запуске приложения, а потом когда вы получите необходимые типы, то будете работать через интерфейсы.

В комментариях привели MEF, но мне думается, что в нем никакой магии нет и он просто элегантно скрывает рефлексию.